# Mediaplayer crashes the app onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, onbackpressed

Can anybody tell me why the back button crashes the app? It doesn't matter what I change in the code, be it a try/catch, onDestroy, onBackPressed, it crashes every time, but only if I have started the media player once. If I haven't started it from the screen, the back button doesn't crash the app. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
public class Lesson1Grammar extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

private SeekBar seekBar;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
MediaPlayer wholeTextPlayer;
private Utilities utils;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lesson1grammar);

    final RelativeLayout playerScreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.playerScreen);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);
    utils = new Utilities();

    final ImageButton btn_player_screen = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_player_screen);
    btn_player_screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //this hides/unhides the part of the layout in which the player is
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (playerScreen.isShown()) {
                playerScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                playerScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    final Button btn_default_acc_whole = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_default_acc_whole);
    btn_default_acc_whole.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {//problem here is
            if (playerState == PlayerState_ScAcc) {
                stopSentencePlayer();
                setEngAu(R.raw.default_acc_audio);
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_DefAcc);
            }else if (playerState == PlayerState_Sc_Paused){
                stopSentencePlayer();
                setEngAu(R.raw.default_acc_audio);
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_DefAcc);
            }else if (playerState == PlayerState_DefAcc) {
                wholeTextPlayer.pause();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_Def_Paused);
            } else if (playerState == PlayerState_Def_Paused) {
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_DefAcc);
            } else {
                setEngAu(R.raw.default_acc_audio);
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_DefAcc);
            }
        }
    });

    final Button btn_scottish_acc_whole = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scottish_acc_whole);
    btn_scottish_acc_whole.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {//problem here is
            if (playerState == PlayerState_DefAcc) {
                stopSentencePlayer();
                setEngAu(R.raw.scottish_acc_audio);
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_ScAcc);
            }else if (playerState == PlayerState_Def_Paused){
                stopSentencePlayer();
                setEngAu(R.raw.scottish_acc_audio);
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_ScAcc);
            }else
            if (playerState == PlayerState_ScAcc) {
                wholeTextPlayer.pause();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_Sc_Paused);
            } else if (playerState == PlayerState_Sc_Paused) {
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_ScAcc);
            } else {
                setEngAu(R.raw.scottish_acc_audio);
                wholeTextPlayer.start();
                setPlayerState(PlayerState_ScAcc);
            }
        }
    });
}

private final int PlayerState_Def_Paused = 1;
private final int PlayerState_Sc_Paused = 2;
private final int PlayerState_DefAcc = 3;
private final int PlayerState_ScAcc = 4;

private int playerState;

private void setPlayerState(int state) {
    playerState = state;
}

public void setEngAu(int engAu) {
    wholeTextPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, engAu);
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.setMax(100);
    updateSeekBar();
}

public void updateSeekBar() {
    handler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = wholeTextPlayer.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = wholeTextPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
        int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = wholeTextPlayer.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
    wholeTextPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
    updateSeekBar();
}

private void stopSentencePlayer() {
    if(wholeTextPlayer !=null){
        try{
            wholeTextPlayer.release();
        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(wholeTextPlayer != null){

            wholeTextPlayer.release();

        }
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

Another option could be to return to the same state of the screen that started the media player and in that case the audio could be paused, etc, but it seems to exceed my capabilities :( The player can play in the background, that's fine.

I hope I captured the right part. I am only a novice :)

```
1-06 17:27:02.909    6596-6596/com.tanuljangolulmenetkozben.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)
        at com.tanuljangolulmenetkozben.app.Lesson1Grammar$4.run(Lesson1Grammar.java:128)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3705)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 17:27:06.022    1675-1835/? E/Omap4ALSA﹕ called drain&close'
```

Comment: I think, your handler continues to run and because you released the MediaPlayer in onBackPressed, `getDuration()` is setting on a null reference. You should interrupt your thread when you release the mediaplayer.

Comment: Thanks @Fllo for the recommendation. I added the following line to the onBackPressed method and it did the trick. handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages (null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, the `Handler` continues to run whereas your `Activity` is destroying when user hits the `onBackPressed()`. Therefore, you have to check if this Handler is running and stop it as you already did in `onStopTrackingTouch()` method:

```
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    ...
}
```

So, `onBackPressed` should looks like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (wholeTextPlayer != null) {
        wholeTextPlayer.release();

        if (handler != null)
            handler.removeCallbacks(null);
    }
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Another good behaviour should to stop it in `onPause` or `onStop`:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (handler != null)
        handler.removeCallbacks(null);
}
```

Comment: It did work, though I had to use handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); because the  handler.removeCallbacks(null); didn't seem to work. I don't really know what the difference is, but the main thing is, that it works. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      if(wholeTextPlayer != null){
      }
 }
};
```

Add if condition and check

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. Fllo's answer helped me. Thank you for trying to help me though :)